# C# creating chart that looks like table

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, charts, microsoft-chart-controls

I'm doing a project where I have data, that can be stored in 2-dimensional array with value in every cell. Each value belongs to equivalent range and color. I need to draw a chart that will be looking like table with painted cells.

e.g. i have |w|hite, |y|ellow, |r|ed and chart should look like:

```
|w||w||w|
|y||y||r|
|r||r||r|
```

In fact, it have to be something like this http://ultra.wroclaw.pl/img/certyfikacje/front_probe.jpg

Is there a way to do that with, e.g. ChartControls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with charts ... or you could do it with other charting (Oxyplot) ... but the question is ... why?

for what you need, I'll say a grid would be far easier and simpler. You can just set the backgrounds on the row/column according to your data.

If you do want to go with charts, you will have to go with boxes/columns, stack them, have a default one, and play around to get what you want.

Comment: Thanks. I tried both ways and seems like the best solution for me is stacked columns chart. Idea with grid is also nice, but I think it hasn't any easy method to deal with axes (which I need).